# Seconds converter

Tags: time, int

```
        Console.Write("Type in the number of seconds: ");
        int total_seconds = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int hours = total_seconds / 3600;
        total_seconds = total_seconds % (hours * 3600);
        int minutes = total_seconds / 60;
        total_seconds = total_seconds % (minutes * 60);
        int seconds = total_seconds;
        Console.WriteLine("Number of hours: " + hours + " hours" + "\nNumber of minutes: " + minutes + " minutes" + "\nNumber of seconds: " + seconds + " seconds");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Managed to create a program that converts a total amount of seconds into it's respective hours, minutes, seconds. I am having a problem though as i wan't the program to also be able to show the amount of hours, minutes etc. for a total amount of seconds below 3660, which doesn't seem to be possible. Any ides how to help fix this issue?

Comment: What language is this? You should add a tag for the language.

Comment: Im not sure the question is clear: Do you mean that you want to convert a number into hours, mins and seconds, but for example, 66 to show 1 minute 6 seconds, OR that you want 3666 to show 1hr, 61 minutes, 3666 seconds?

Comment: I'm new to this site, but i will remember putting a laungauge tag in my future question. This particular piece of code is C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
Chowlett's answer does this more elegantly - use his code.

This seems to work for me (by the `if` statements I make sure that I don't get a division by zero in case `hours` our `minutes` are zero:

```
int total_seconds = 3640;

int hours = 0;
int minutes = 0;
int seconds = 0;

if (total_seconds >= 3600)
{
    hours = total_seconds / 3600;
    total_seconds = total_seconds % (hours * 3600);
}

if (total_seconds >= 60)
{
    minutes = total_seconds / 60;
    total_seconds = total_seconds % (minutes * 60);
}

seconds = total_seconds;
Console.WriteLine("Number of hours: " + hours + " hours" + "\nNumber of minutes: " + minutes + " minutes" + "\nNumber of seconds: " + seconds + " seconds");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem's in the lines where you take the modulus (the `%` operator). You want the number of seconds left after removing all the whole hours, which is `total_seconds % 3600`. The code you have, if you have below 3600 seconds, will try to do `total_seconds % 0`, which is a division-by-zero. Try the following:

```
int hours = total_seconds / 3600;
total_seconds = total_seconds % 3600;
int minutes = total_seconds / 60;
total_seconds = total_seconds % 60;
int seconds = total_seconds;
```

Comment: @user1696992 - No worries. And welcome to Stack Overflow! You can also "accept" this answer as correct by clicking the green check-mark beside it.